# CMD file fails if %1 parameter includes parenthesis or parentheses

Tags: cmd, parameters, parentheses

I have a Windows CMD file that IFs %1. But if %1 includes a parenthesis, the batch file interprets the parenthesis as either opening a command or closing it or both.

How do I safely IF or FOR a parameter named, for instance, "File Copy (3).txt"?

It took me forever to figure out what was happening, why sometimes there was no problem and sometimes it just freaked out. I need to flesh this out just a bit more, error-check for success or failure rather than assume, and restore the CALLs I eliminated while pulling out my hair. If it helps, though, I'm copying in what I have.

I KNOW that "%~1" is dumb; I'm stripping off the quotation marks and putting them around it again. That hasn't helped.

Including SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion at the top of the CMD file doesn't help either.

What am I not understanding about how IF works?

Code follows:

```
@cls                  & REM blank gratuitous error message when run from server
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: ONLY THE NEXT TWO LINES MAY BE CUSTOMIZED BY THE USER
set _CAT=DigitalCAT
set _User=Timothy McGowan
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Set up two more variables
set _Server=\\[path blanked; nonpublic server]
set _Path=%_Server%\%_CAT%\%_User%
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::----------                                                        top of loop
:Loop
::----------
If "%~1"=="" (goto Done)

:: Get chunks of name from first parameter on command line.
:: _fnam is just file name without path or quotes.
:: _tnam is just file name without path, quotes, or extension.
:: _yr is first four characters of file name, which is supposed to be a year.
:: _mo holds the 6th and 7th characters of the file name and should be
::     among the numbers 01 through 12.
:: Better error checking would determine whether a space or mark of punctuation
::     separates the first four characters.  A file name such as
::     20160126... could get filed in December rather than January.
::     So IF the fifth character is a digit, use that and next; else,
::        use sixth and seventh.
   set _fnam=%~nx1
   set _yr=%_fnam:~0,4%
   set _mox=%_fnam:~5,2%
   if %_mox%==01 (set _mo=01 - January)   & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==02 (set _mo=02 - February)  & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==03 (set _mo=03 - March)     & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==04 (set _mo=04 - April)     & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==05 (set _mo=05 - May)       & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==06 (set _mo=06 - June)      & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==07 (set _mo=07 - July)      & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==08 (set _mo=08 - August)    & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==09 (set _mo=09 - September) & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==10 (set _mo=10 - October)   & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==11 (set _mo=11 - November)  & goto MonthSet
   if %_mox%==12 (set _mo=12 - December)  & goto MonthSet
   Goto BadMonth

::----------
:MonthSet            & REM Skip "Goto Badmonth" command, the catchall rerouter.
::----------
:: Find out whether first four digits of file name are a year,
:: and whether that year is a folder's name within user's folder.
:: If not, create folder in NewYear procedure.

   if NOT exist "%_Path%\%_yr%\" (
      echo.
      echo %_yr% is not yet a folder in your storage space.
      echo Is this a new year, or did you typo the year in the file name?
      echo The file's name needs to be in [year-month-day Judge] format.
      echo For instance, "2016-10-22 Perkkio" works, but "20161022 Perkkio" does not.
      echo Your file is named %_fnam%.
      echo.
      echo Either...
      echo Press A to Add %_yr%
      echo or...
      echo Press C to Cancel so you can rename the file.
      choice /N /C CA
      if errorlevel 2 (
         MD "%_Path%\%_yr%"
         echo %date% %time%:  Created %_yr% folder>>"%_Path%\%_yr%\Log.txt"
         goto YearAdded
      )
      if errorlevel 1 (
         set _errFlag=1
         echo.>>"%_Path%\ErrorMessages.txt"
         echo %date% %time%:  ERROR!  FOLLOWING FILE NOT COPIED:>>"%_Path%\ErrorMessages.txt"
         echo %_fnam%>>"%_Path%\ErrorMessages.txt"
         goto End
      )
   )

::----------
:YearAdded
::----------
:: Folder Year should now exist on server.
:: If necessary, quietly create new Month folder in Year folder.
   if NOT exist "%_Path%\%_yr%\%_mo%" (
      MD "%_Path%\%_yr%\%_mo%"
      echo %date% %time%:  Created %_yr%\%_mo% folder>>"%_Path%\%_yr%\Log.txt"

   )

::----------
:: If file already uploaded, handle; else, just copy.
   if exist "%_Path%\%_yr%\%_mo%\%_fnam%" (
      echo.
      echo %_Path%\%_yr%\%_mo%\%_fnam% aleady exists.
      echo.
      echo You may...
      echo    Press R to replace the copy you already uploaded,
      echo.
      echo    Press S to skip this file,
      echo Or...
      echo    Press Q to quit.
      choice /N /C QSR
         if errorlevel 3 (
            copy /y "%~1" "%_Path%\%_yr%\%_mo%"
            echo %date% %time%:  %_fnam% replaced in %_yr%\%_mo%>>"%_Path%\%_yr%\Log.txt"
            SHIFT
            GOTO LOOP
         )
         if errorlevel 2 (
            echo %date% %time%:  %_fnam% not replaced in %_yr%\%_mo%>>"%_Path%\%_yr%\Log.txt"
            SHIFT
            GOTO LOOP
         )
         if errorlevel 1 (
            set _errFlag=1
            echo.>>"%_Path%\ErrorMessages.txt"
            echo %date% %time%:  ERROR!  FOLLOWING FILE NOT COPIED:>>"%_Path%\ErrorMessages.txt"
            echo %_fnam%>>"%_Path%\ErrorMessages.txt"
            goto End
         )

   ) ELSE (
      copy "%~1" "%_Path%\%_yr%\%_mo%"
      echo %date% %time%:  %_fnam% copied to %_yr%\%_mo%>>"%_Path%\%_yr%\Log.txt"
      SHIFT
      GOTO LOOP
   )

::                                                               bottom of loop
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::----------
:BadMonth
::----------
   echo.
   echo ERROR!
   echo "%_mox%" is not a valid month.
   echo The file's name needs to be in [year-month-day Judge] format.
   echo For instance, "2016-10-22 Perkkio" works, but "20161022 Perkkio" does not.
   echo.
   echo Your file is named:
   echo %_fnam%
   echo.
   echo Please rename the file and use this utility again.
goto VeryEnd
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::----------
:Done
::----------
   echo.
   echo No more files found to copy.
goto End
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
::----------                              Allow user to read results on screen.
:End
::----------
if .%_errFlag%.==.1. (
   type "%_Path%\ErrorMessages.txt"
   echo.
   echo NOTE FILES NOT COPIED ABOVE.
)
echo.
pause

::----------
:VeryEnd
::----------
:: cls
```

Comment: Please belay responding. Must be a syntax error in there somewhere. A targeted batch file works fine. This time. But I haven't tried nested IF statements in it either, so I may renew this matter.

Comment: Never fails. Can't find my own error until I embarrass myself in public. Needed some quotation marks around variables. Wondered why no one else had a similar problem. Now I know!

Answer (score 0):

Never fails. Can't find my own error until I embarrass myself in public. Needed some quotation marks around the _fnam variables. Wondered why no one else had a similar problem with parentheses. Now I know!

Cleaned up that code and fixed some cut-and-paste residue, and it's working as intended. Would love to rewrite with internal calls to labels, but I think at this point I'll leave well enough alone.